# how to fit quadratic with plateau condition in matlab?

Tags: matlab, quadratic

[image]

The values of x and y are as follows:

```
x=[0,80,100,120,150], 
y=[1865,3608,4057,4343,4389]
```

My equations are as follows:

```
y=a(x)^2+b(x)+c, x < xc(Ymax) ....(1)

y=yp, x >= xc(Ymax) ....(2)
```

I want to fit these two equations, where first equation will provide a quadratic fit whereas the second equation will provide a linear one. The problem is when we are trying to fit, it provide us best fit in quadratic form (eq.1), it did not include the linear fit (eq.2).

We are also providing the MATLAB code that we have used:

```
yf = @(b,x) b(1).*x.^2+b(2)*x+b(3);
B0 = [0.006; 21; 1878];
[Bm,normresm] = fminsearch(@(b) norm(y - yf(b,x)), B0);
a=Bm(1);
b=Bm(2);
c=Bm(3);
xc=-b/(2*a);
p=c-(b^2/(4*a));
 if (x < xc) 
      yfit = a.*x.^2+ b*x+c;
 else yfit = p;
 end
plot(x,yfit)
hold on 
plot(x,y,'*')
hold off
```

We are providing the graph (fig(1)) which we got from our results. For further understanding, we are also proving a graph (fig(2)) which shows how the result should come.

[image]

Comment: does the xc point belong to the input x array? Is it the x value corresponding to the maximum y value?

Comment: yes, xc is the critical value of x at which y is maximum.

Comment: I asked you because the last picture shows something different. So in the depicted case the maximum y value is somewhere where the quadratic function meets the plateau part, isn't it? And in your case it would be the last point. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

I modified the input data so you can see the result:

```
%input data
x = [0;     20;     50;     80;     100;    120;    150;    160;    180;    200;    220;     240]; 
y = [1865;  2500;  3000;   3608;   4057;   4343;   4389;    4250;   4300;   4280;   4350;    4200];

%find the index of the maximum y value
[~, idx] = max(y);

%initial parameter values
a0 = -1;
b0 = 1;
c0 = 2;

p0 = [a0 b0 c0];

%optimization options
options = optimset('Display','iter');

%optimization call
p = fminsearch(@fun_so_180730, p0, options, x, y, idx);

%plot of the fitted function based on two parts (quadratic and linear)
x_fit_1 = (0:2:x(idx))'; 
x_fit_2 = (x(idx):2:max(x))';

y_fit_1 = p(1)*x_fit_1.^2 + p(2)*x_fit_1 + p(3);
y_fit_2 = ones(size(x_fit_2))*y_fit_1(end);

figure;
plot(x, y, 'bo');
hold on;
plot([x_fit_1; x_fit_2], [y_fit_1; y_fit_2], 'r-');
hold off;
grid on;
```

The optimization function as a separate file:

```
function [f] = fun_so_180730(p, x, y, idx)

    a = p(1);
    b = p(2);
    c = p(3);

    % calculation of the current function
    y_prime = zeros(size(y));

    %quadratic part
    y_prime(1:idx) = a*x(1:idx).^2 + b*x(1:idx) + c;

    %linear part if there are elements after the maximum y value
    if (idx < numel(y))
        y_prime(idx+1:end) = y_prime(idx);
    end

    % current cost as a vector norm
    f = norm(y - y_prime);
end
```

Result:

[image: piecewise curve fitting using the fminsearch optimizer]